# Undefined offset 1 with $qString

Tags: php, qstring

Trying to clean up a site and we have this error that keeps showing

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/includes/client.controller.php
> on line 34 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
> /var/www/includes/client.controller.php on line 39.

Im new to this and hoping someone may spot the what I've missed in the code below.

```
        $qString = explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        $qString = $qString[1];
        foreach (explode('&', $qString) as $q)
        {
            $parts = explode('=', $q);
            $key = $parts[0];
            $val = urlencode($parts[1]);
            if (!isset($_GET[$key]))
                $_GET[$key] = $val;
        }
```

Comment: URL likely isn't always a GET.. `$qString = !empty($qString[1]) ? $qString[1] : FALSE;`.. not sure how `explode` will behave on `FALSE` though.. might want to `if` that loop

Comment: print_r(  $qString); and see what you get and also exit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to account for the fact that not URLs will have a querystring. So you need to check if `$qString[1]` before accessing it to avoid the warning.

```
    $qString = explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if(isset($qString[1])) {
        $qString = $qString[1];
        foreach (explode('&', $qString) as $q)
        {
            $parts = explode('=', $q);
            $key = $parts[0];
            $val = urlencode($parts[1]);
            if (!isset($_GET[$key]))
                $_GET[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
```

Also, I am not sure about the logic here, it seems like this code is recreating the `$_GET` system variable from the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`? If it's about urlencoding the values, you can just loop $_GET to do the same.

Comment: Thank you all, this solved that mystery. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Great to hear that! If this solved your problem, please mark the answer a the accepted one, so that you can help people in the future to quickly identify the correct fix.